# Load texture with only alpha values

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have 3D data represents alpha values, how can I load this to 3D  texture with only alpa values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single channel texture format. For <=OpenGL-2.1 this would be GL_ALPHA. Beginning with OpenGL-3 you'd use GL_R and a shader passing the r-component to the output fragment alpha channel